# Can I make Ubuntu server connect to wifi and create an Access point from the same wlan0 interface?

Tags: server, wireless-access-point

Currently i have an Ubuntu 12.04 server vanilla install(no packages installed) on PC1 and xubuntu desktop on PC2.
Both run the x64 distros.

PC1 has only 1 wifi card connected (UBDOnt-8 under rt2800usb driver) which is able to connect to the internet.
The network i am connecting to is a neighbours open wifi on channel 11(meaning no physical access there).

What i d like to accomplish is to create an AP on PC1 on the same device so PC2 and every other wireless capable device can connect to that. I guess there is no need for channel hopping support.

So far i was able to create the AP , visible from PC2 , but it can't connect .
I guess i am doing something wrong on the bridging settings. What i have googled so far wasn't really helpful as it has to do with bridging from eth0 to wlan0.

Answer (score 1):

No, you need two networks for this. Wi-Fi is EITHER in AP or Ad-Hoc modes not both.

If your neighbour is allowing you to connect to his Wi-Fi, just connect all of the PC's to it. If they don't know what you are doing, I strongly suggest that you don't do it! It may well be illegal depending on what country you are in.

When bridging, you need two connections not one. You could bridge a wired and wireless or two wireless connections.